# Message passing between content scripts and background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message

I have injected content scripts to all frames. I sent a request from background and would like to receive response from all the content scripts (frames that have been injected).

Currently I can only receive one response, how do I receive responses from all content scripts?

content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(   
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    if (request.bgReq == "windowInfo")
    alert("bgreq received : "+ window.location.host);

});
```

background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(sentWords) {
    if (sentWords.words == "injection") {
        //send request to content scritps
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {bgReq:"windowInfo"});
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly send it to all tabs in all the windows :

```
chrome.windows.getAll({},function(windows){
  for( var win in windows ){
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs) {
      for (var i in tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {bgReq:"windowInfo"});
      }
    });
  }
});
```